# JQuery - Form Submit - Many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I got a quick question, on my javascript code I've this:

```js
 $('form').submit( function (e) {
  var form = $(this);
  console.log('submit attempt');
  $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
   var attr = $(this).attr('required');
   if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false || (attr = 'Y' && $(this).val() != '') ) {
    if($(this).hasClass('numeric')) {
     if(isNumber($(this).val())) {
      $(form).submit();
     }
    }
    else {
     $(form).submit();
    }
   }
   else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
   }
  });
 });
```

And on console log I got over 1300 messages of 'submit attempt' then an error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Do you guys have any idea why this happens and how to solve it? Maybe some tricky thing about submit() I forgot about ?

If needed more informations please tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: You should remove `$(form).submit();` from loop because it causes multiple form submit recursively.

Comment: The problem is that you are submitting the form again within a submit calling it recursively

Comment: Oh right! Do you know how can I submit the form when I'm on the if condition without making it into a loop?

I mean: If condition is true send the form, else preventDefault.... writing nothing on the condition is enough?

Comment: If your .submit() event handler gets to the end without a `e.preventDefault()` then the form will submit.    You can `return` at any time (being careful that you're not returning from an inline function like in `$.each`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there isn't an error, the form gets submitted with every input or textarea.

So, first loop the fields, define if there is a failure. If not, send it:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var failure = false;
  console.log('submit attempt');
  $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('required');
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false || (attr = 'Y' && $(this).val() != '')) {
      failure = true;
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('numeric') && !isNumber($(this).val())) {
      failure = true;
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
  });
  if (failure) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: This still calls `.submit()` from within `.submit()` which will have the same problem (just less so).  Simply doesn't need the final `.submit()` and let the event complete without being prevented.

Comment: @freedomn-m, your right... the last `else{}` can be removed, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! I did like you said: "If your .submit() event handler gets to the end without a e.preventDefault() then the form will submit. "

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are submitting the form again within a submit calling it recursively. This is how you should do it. if validation fails isValid contains false and stops form from submitting;

```
    $('form').submit(function(e){
var isValid = true;
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
            var attr = $(this).attr('required');
            if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false || (attr = 'Y' && $(this).val() != '') ) {
                if($(this).hasClass('numeric')) {
                    if(!isNumber($(this).val())) {
                        isValid = false;
            return isValid;
                    } else {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
                     }
                }

            }
            else {
        e.preventDefault();
                $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
        isValid = false;
        return isValid;
            }
        });
  return isValid;

});
```